# Как анимировать изменение focusRect или focusPoint в Yandex map kit

Tags: ios, swift, yandexmapkit

Проблема следующая: нужно приподнимать карту с `cameraPosition` по центру чуть выше при выдвижении шторки снизу как это сделано в Яндекс GO. Пробовал привязывать низ `view` с картой к верху этой шторки констрэйнтами. По идее работает, но сама анимация изменения констрэйнтов имеет такой эффект: снизу и сверху карт проскакивает задний фон и сама карта дергается. Видимо, карта рендерится с некоторыми лагами. Как вариант я сделал изменение `focusRect` или `focusPoint` у `mapWindow`. Но эти изменения происходят моментально и их не получается анимировать. В Яндекс Go при выдвигании шторки снизу карта чуть смещается вверх вместе с пином. Это происходит плавно и анимируется. Пока такого добиться не получается. Кто знает как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, сделал так: при поднятии шторки снизу смещаем карту на ту дельту по высоте, где должно быть в итоге `cameraPosition`. Смещаем анимированно. При этом в `completion` блоке меняем `focusRect` у `mapWindow` и делаем смещение карты на эту дельту, но НЕ анимированно. В итоге получаем плавную анимацию. Если нужно перенести пин вместе с этим - устанавливаем `frame` пина в `listener` перемещения карты.

Comment: Вы бы код приложили.. )

Answer (score 0):

Вообще использование **focusRect** тут кажется более логичным, чем работа с блоками.

Только встроенного анимированного изменения **focusRect** нет, такую анимацию нужно реализовать самостоятельно.
Готового примера анимации не встречал, вот лишь общий подход, описанный знающими людьми (не моё):

> "Выставить FocusRect в итоговое состояние, вычислить итоговое
> положение камеры, затем вернуть исходное состояние FocusRect и начать
> его анимировать до итогового."

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. В итоге сделал похожим образом!